# U.S. Expat living in Poland working remotely for a U.S. Institution: How to classify myself for taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, working-abroad, poland

Briefly, I am a U.S. citizen living in Poland. Recently, I was offered a paid remote position at a research group with a U.S. university. Due to the nature of the work, I can either be considered an employee of the university (W2) or an independent contractor (1099), and the employer has given me that choice. I want to avoid being double taxed.

If I go with W2, I know that the employer will withhold some income, and then with the remainder I will have to pay Polish tax. Later I can apply for a tax return from the U.S. under a foreign exclusion, correct?

Would a 1099 be better in that case, since I won't have to wait for a U.S. tax return next year?

Which would be better for me?

Some relevant info:

- I am authorized to work in Poland
- I do not expect to make more than $25k from this position